# Is there a command to "manually automount" an attached disk?

Tags: nautilus, mount, automount

I have an extra hard drive which I use for backups. The label on its one and only partition is "backup". When I open nautilus and click on "backup" it mounds the drive in "/media/backup", and then there's a little eject button next to it's icon in nautilus.

If I manually mount the drive by creating a directory and using "sudo mount /dev/sdx /some/dir", the eject icon still shows up in nautilus, but when I press it I get an error because the device was not mounted via whatever it is that mounts it the other way.

What I would like is to be able to do this "mount to /media/backup and enable the eject button" via the command line. The goal is to have the device mounted by a script which needs the drive, but then leave it mounted until I manually eject it... if I want to.

P.S. I'm aware that I can have the drive auto mounted at startup, but that's not what I'm looking for here, and I'd like to know if this is possible.

Clarification: I'm looking for a command to "mount the drive the way nautilus would". This should create the directory "/media/backup", mount the device to that directory, and then when I press the eject button from nautilus, it should unmount the device and delete the directory.

Comment: I'm struggling with something like this, but with an [encrypted internal drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103835/securely-automount-encrypted-drive-at-user-login). Hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

you can automount, you can manually mount but you can't manually-automount!

Use gconf-editor or dconf-editor and change the preferences.

/apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount

/apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount_open/apps/nautilus/preferences

/media_autorun_never

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/yourblockdevice
```

Worked for me. Adapted from https://superuser.com/questions/638225/manually-trigger-automount-in-debian-based-linux

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-o user` to your mount command.

Comment: well mount still requires that the directory already exist. The nautilus action 1) creates the directory and 2) mounts to it.